# Error codes handling on vb.net post

Tags: vb.net, httpwebrequest

How do I handel error codes from remote site so that every time I could return remote sites output. Now remote site is giving me status 400. I know there more information after that response, but my application refuses not to show it becouse of error on line. Anna error is there becouse of status code 400.

->> response = request.GetResponse()

```
Public Function SendPostData(ByVal site As String, ByVal message As String)

    Dim request As WebRequest
    request = WebRequest.Create(site)
    Dim response As WebResponse
    Dim postData As String = message
    Dim data As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)


    request.Method = "POST"
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    request.ContentLength = data.Length

    Dim stream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
    stream.Close()

    response = request.GetResponse()
    Dim sr As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())


     Return "" & sr.ReadToEnd


End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You are nearly there. You just need to keep reading the stream until you reach the end:

```
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder
        Using reader As New StreamReader(rsp.GetResponseStream)
            Do Until reader.EndOfStream
                sb.Append(reader.ReadLine())
            Loop
        End Using
        Return sb.ToString
```

The following is a method I wrote to handle this sort of thing:

```
Public Shared Function PostWebData(ByVal uri As String, ByVal data As String, Optional contentType As String = "text/xml", Optional useDefaultProxy As Boolean = True) As String
    Dim req As WebRequest = Nothing
    Dim rsp As WebResponse = Nothing
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    Try
        req = WebRequest.Create(uri)
        If useDefaultProxy Then req.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy
        req.Method = "POST"
        req.ContentType = contentType
        Using writer As New StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream)
            writer.WriteLine(data)
            writer.Close()
        End Using

        rsp = req.GetResponse
        Using reader As New StreamReader(rsp.GetResponseStream)
            Do Until reader.EndOfStream
                sb.Append(reader.ReadLine())
            Loop
        End Using
        Return sb.ToString
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return ""
    Finally
        If Not req Is Nothing Then req.GetRequestStream.Close()
        If Not rsp Is Nothing Then rsp.GetResponseStream.Close()
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: where is this part ErrorHandling.ThrowExceptionEx ?  When I tryed your code it made error:BC30451: 'ErrorHandling' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: That's an internal method in my code just rem it out

Comment: I needed to get that post response with erros. now it's working but i have no clue what wrong on remote site becouse i can not see the actual response. I know the actual response has Status 400 but at the same time the erro page is showing me the actual error reason. I need that reason from remote site.

Comment: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.  All i get now it that. on remote site there is detailed information about the reson of status 400.  How do I recieve the reson from remote site after post?